# Google Cloud SQL Server data to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I need to export the data that I have in a Google Cloud SQL Server database to BigQuery in order to make some data analysis and reporting. I found that the recommended way to do that is using `BigQuery Cloud SQL federated query` but this doesn't support SQL Server database, only MySql and Postgres in Google Cloud SQL service.

I'm looking for a way to do that with the Google Cloud resources, maybe a batch ETL tool or a streaming one. A requirement is that the data in BigQuery should be refreshed in real-time or near to real time. I'm pretty new to Google Cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Write a Pubsub client server context that can publish to a Pubsub topic. This client will be used  for  (1) the Worker when it finishes creating an analysis and (2) the Exporter when it finishes exporting data. you can refer [this](https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/publisher/index.html) link